# Gson fromJson/Deserialize to instance

Tags: java, json, gson

code first.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// 1.
ClassA a = gson.fromJson(json, ClassA.class)
gson.fromJson(jsonB, a)// make jsonB to a

// 2.
ClassB b = new ClassB();
b.setXXX(xxx);
b.setYYY(yyy);
......
gson.fromJson(json, b)// make json to b
```

Is this possible ? how ?

**EDIT**

```
// JSON A

{
    "name":"wener"
}

// JSON B
{
    "age":22
}

// CLASS A
class A
{
    String name;
    Integer age;
}

// 
//
A a = gson.fromJson(JsonA, A.class)
// try to do somgthing like this
// this part is what I want to do.
gson.fromJson(JsonB, a)

// then
assert a.getName().equals("wener")
assert a.getAge().equals(22)
```

So, just need something like this. `fromJsonToInstance(String, Object);`

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you want to know how Gson creates object proxies?  Or do you want to know how it injects values?

Comment: I update my question, and found a way for myself.but this involved another Gson instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Test
public void testMergeObject()
{
    String jsonA = "{\"name\":\"wener\"}";
    String jsonB = "{\"age\":22}";
    Person person = new Person();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Person.class, new InstanceCreatorWithInstance<>(person)).create();
    gson.fromJson(jsonA, Person.class);
    gson.fromJson(jsonB, Person.class);

    assert person.getName().equals("wener");
    assert person.getAge().equals(22);
}
@Data
static class Person
{
    String name;
    Integer age;
}
static class InstanceCreatorWithInstance<T> implements InstanceCreator<T>
{
    T instance;

    public InstanceCreatorWithInstance(T instance)
    {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    @Override
    public T createInstance(Type type)
    {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Now, I know what I want to do is change the instance creation process.